# aggregation lookup and match a nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hello i am trying to join two collections...

#COLLECTION 1

```
const valuesSchema= new Schema({
    value: { type: String },
})

const categoriesSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    values: [valuesSchema]
    })

mongoose.model('categories', categoriesSchema )
```

#COLLECTION 2

```
const productsSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    categories: [{
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'categories',
        }]
    })

mongoose.model('productos', productsSchema )
```

Now, what i pretend to do is join these collections and have an output like this.

#Example Product Document

```
{
    name: 'My laptop',
    description: 'Very ugly laptop',
    categories: ['5f55949054f3f31db0491b5c','5f55949054f3f31db0491b5b'] // these are _id of valuesSchema
}
```

#Expected Output

```
{
    name: 'My laptop',
    description: 'Very ugly laptop',
    categories: [{value: 'Laptop'}, {value: 'PC'}]
}
```

This is what i tried.

```
                 {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: "categories",
                            let: { "categories": "$categories" },
                            as: "categories",
                            pipeline: [
                             {
                                $match: {
                                    $expr: {
                                        $in: [ '$values._id','$$categories']
                                    },
                                }
                             },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
```

but this query is not matching... Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you try to use the non-co-related queries, I appreciate it, you can easily achieve with `$unwind` to flat the array and then `$match`. To regroup the array we use `$group`. The `$reduce` helps to move on each arrays and store some particular values.

```
 [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      let: {
        "categories": "$categories"
      },
      as: "categories",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: "$values"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$values._id",
                "$$categories"
              ]
            },
            
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            values: {
              $addToSet: "$values"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      categories: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$categories",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$this.values",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo template](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3EBn4GKjyqZ)

Comment: I'm not a node.js guy. I tried to help you, if there is any mistake, let me know

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

- `$lookup` with categories
- `$unwind` deconstruct `values` array
- `$match` categories id with value id
- `$project` to show required field

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      let: { cat: "$categories" },
      as: "categories",
      pipeline: [
        { $unwind: "$values" },
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$values._id", "$$cat"] } } },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            value: "$values.value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ms2Nm4Qehln)

Comment: this is the expected output, but you are missing something, what products.categories has  are values' _id

Comment: yep something still bad, the products.categories containes values _id, so in your example it would have for example categories['1','2']

Comment: exactly that is what is missing, the rest i think is perfect